# Как сделать текст градиентом?

Tags: html, css

```
            <div class="promo_desc">
                <p>Автогамак<br />
                Для Собак<br />
                В Машину<br />
                3х слойный<br />
                от 2390 р.</p>
            </div>
```

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как такое реализовать на CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40vh;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem<br>ipsum</h1>
```

Comment: Ещё можно `color: transparent;` заменить на что-то, у чего поддержка такая же, как у обрезки фона. Тогда будет во всяких IE адекватно.